# How to create Inverse Distance Weight of points and sum the result (not interpolate)?

Tags: arcmap, buffer, geopandas, inverse-distance-weighted

I have a list of point locations and I would like to create an IDW result that does not interpolate, but sums instead.  So, each point would have a bullseye pattern around it, but there would be summation in the areas where the bullseyes overlap. I would like to know if there is an ESRI ArcMap tool that can accomplish this, but do not want to build a GIS model in ESRI.  If a list of several functions is needed, then I would prefer to use python/geopandas to solve the problem.  Is there a tool out there that can solve this problem?  I was hoping to find "IDW Summation" but only found interpolation tools.

I considered doing concentric ring buffers around each point, and then intersecting the overlaps, but I would need to create multiple concentric rings at fine spacings in order to get a "continuous" gradient result.

Another solution I can think of is to perform IDW Interpolation on each data point individually, and then find a way to sum the raster values across all results.  However, this would get very messy with so many points (over 100).

The third solution I am currently using is to generate a near table and use a fine grid mesh polygon.  Then I will do inverse distance computations using the distance from the near table, and update the grid mesh dbf with the new attribute.  However, this gets strange when the point is within a polygon, because distance is zero.

Comment: Please decide which software you want to use, otherwise answers can't be complete.

Comment: If there is a tool in ArcGIS that would be great, but I can use geopandas if it's complicated.

Comment: That is no real decision if you ask me, but hey.